# Contrapostive proof with "if there exist A and B, then C"

Tags: linear-algebra, predicate-logic

Considering the statement: "Let Q be a symmetric matrix. If there exist positive and negative elements in the diagonal, then Q is indefinite."

Is the contrapositive of the statement: If Q is not indefinite, then all diagonal elements are either not postive or not negative (meaning all diagonals are of one sign).

I thought proving the contrapositive would be easier than the original statement, but I just wanted to make sure the above is actually the contrapositive.

Comment: Is your initial statement supposed to be then Q is indefinite?

Comment: you also have to consider zero elements if positive/negative is taken in strict sense (in which case "all diagonal elements are the same sign or zero".

Answer (score 1):

The direct proof is easy. Say without loss of generality that the $q_{1,1}$ is positive and $q_{2,2}$ is negative, then we have that
$$
e_1^TQe_1=q_{1,1}>0
$$
and
$$
e_2^TQe_2=q_{2,2}<0
$$
so we have that $Q$ represents an indefinite quadratic form.